# How Create a right click context menu when I click on marker in Google map Using java Script

Tags: javascript, google-maps, right-click

I have developed a javascrit code which shows google map.When I click in map it creates a marker.

now what is i want, when i click on marker is should show **right click menu** at clicked location.

Answer (score -1):

Try the [GMAP3](http://gmap3.net/) library. It adds an abstraction over googles javascript api, which allows you to implement features like context menu's in a simpler fashion.

They even have a tutorial on how to use GMAP3 to create context menus - http://gmap3.net/en/pages/19-demo/

Comment: I agree that the example is good, but link only posts are discouraged on SO.  A year or two from now, this link may be dead and will not help anyone.

Comment: fair - however my answer wasn't "the tutorial". It's more about suggesting to use the GMAP3 library. I've reworded to reflect that.